# PhpStorm - How To Add Space Inside Blade Curly Braces

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-blade

I was using SublimeText3 and when I open `{{` it was automatically closed and looking like this (A space middle of braces):
 `{{ }}`.

With PhpStorm braces looks like this (No space):
`{{}}`

You know most people using space like this: `{{ route('route') }}`. I've search IDE settings but can't figured out. Is there an option or something for this?

Comment: Just press a space after typing `{{` (so it's `{{[SPACE]` -- IDE will make it to be `{{ | }}` (where `|` represents caret position).

Comment: I know but I'm asking is there a setting/option for do that automatically (Without press space).

Comment: There is no such option in PhpStorm settings.

Comment: for me, it's not even closing the braces. I'm using phpstorm with vim idea. till  now I didn't find any option to solve it

Comment: Question answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76845645/phpstorm-how-to-add-spaces-inside-laravel-blade-curly-braces