# PhpStorm - How to add spaces inside Laravel Blade curly braces

Tags: phpstorm

I was using VS Code and when I open `{{` it was automatically closed and looked like this (a space in the middle of braces): `{{ }}`.

With PhpStorm braces looks like this (no space): `{{}}`

**In short:** I want to have `{{ $post->title }}` instead of `{{$post->title}}`

Comment: The space in between is as a result of extension installed on vscode. So you need the extension as well on phpStorm or need to modify the laravel blade extension setting on phpStorm.

Comment: @IbrahimHammed I already have the blade extension, but I don't know how to modify it

Comment: I'm using Twig and the plugin has an option to add (or not) spaces inside curly braces in Settings > Editor > Code style > Twig. I've installed the Laravel Blade plugin to check if such a feature exists, and it doesn't. You can only choose the size of tabs. So I guess the short answer is : you can't. I suggest you make a feature request to Jetbrains. It seems sensible to add it.

Comment: @Halibut thank you so much. I'll send a request about it to JetBrains. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not yet possible, and we already have a request for that: [WI-27472](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27472/Blade-support-spaces-formatting-code-style-for-brackets)

Answer (score 3):

Since at the moment this setting is not implemented, then you can create a "Live Template" that is applied in HTML.

```
{{ $END$ }}
```

[image]

---

Or when autocomplete is triggered, just hit Space:

[image]